# intel xdk test cache

Tags: caching, intel-xdk

I'm making an app using the Intel XDK.
I'm also using the "app preview" app on a Galaxy Tab 2.
My problem is that when I "push" files to the Intel servers to load onto my device, there seems to be either a delay, or a caching issue because I'm getting what I KNOW is old js and css code.
The HTML file seems to change just fine.

As a work-around, I was loading my js file with a unique number in the src, like this:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/ae.js?ver=abc123"></script>
```

but now even that only works sometimes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen sporadically.  The webview *should* clear out the files.  Have you tried using the Debug tab and testing through App Preview?  It will load Crosswalk then for you.  This lets you connect your device through USB and debug in a much faster way.